# Why don't opaque objects reflect light?

Tags: optics, reflection, optical-materials

My sister was doing a quiz and I tried to point her in the right direction by giving her scenarios to imagine. One of the questions in the quiz was:

Which of the following objects do not reflect light:

1. Polished metal
2. Mirror
3. Undisturbed water
4. Book

She suggested that the answer was "undisturbed water" and that made sense to me too.

But the answer given was "book", which didn't make sense to me. How can you even see the book if it didn't reflect light in the first place?

Is this terrible framing by her teacher or am I having a conceptual misunderstanding?

Comment: Oh, my! that quiz question is terrible! What if the book is bright  glowing blue? :)

Comment: The book is most definitely wrong wrong wrong.  Everything reflects a portion of incoming light (save a  perfectly created 1/4-wave coating and infinitely narrowband wavelength)

Comment: I wonder if teacher's question may be getting at the difference between "reflected" light and "scattered" light.  See https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-difference-between-scattering-and-reflection; or https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-scattering-and-reflection

Comment: The real lesson that one takes out of school is that there's plenty of incompetent teachers out there (and that you may sadly have to suck it up and play along, and that life is unfair, and the list goes on...)

Comment: None of the choices is right. You never seen your reflection in a pond?

Comment: In a mostly colloquial sense, a book does not reflect light. It absorbs light and re-emits it - mostly at a different frequency. While technically there is some small amount of reflection and refraction, comparing that surface to the other 3 one can intuit what the (poorly worded) question was getting at. Some book coatings though are quite reflective meaning you can see a reflection of the light source quite easily.

Comment: @nasu You can’t see a reflection in water if the water is undisturbed. Light is reflected after photons interact with (disturb) the surface molecules and atoms.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft FWIW, black-painted, rough-cut book pages, edge-on would fairly well approximate a blackbody perfect absorber.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I wouldn’t say everything because if it’s not disturbed then there is no light to reflect.

Comment: @Bill Alsept Are you serious or just kidding? Undisturbed here means flat, without waves. Like water in a pond in a day withour wind. According to your meaning it should say that the light is reflected by disturbed mirrors?

Comment: @nasu yeah I would assume that’s what it means too but a quiz is a quiz and it says undisturbed water.

Comment: Even in a quiz you still use the usual meaning of words, unless therwise stated.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflecting_pool

Comment: Water does not reflect light. If it reflected light, you would not be able to see through it. When you look at a reflection on the surface of a still pond, it's not the water per se that is reflecting the light. Instead, it's more meaningful to say that the reflection comes from the _boundary_ between two different materials—water and air—that have different [refractive indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)#Reflection_of_light

Comment: @SolomonSlow It is reflecting 0 to 16% of the light. Just like glass and other transparent surfaces.

Comment: @SolomonSlow If some light encounters some water and is reflected as a result of that encounter, I would certainly describe that event as "the water reflected the light." How would you define the word "reflect" in such a way that the statement "water does not reflect light" is true?

Comment: @TannerSwett Words and phrases have different meanings in different contexts. It's perfectly reasonable to say, "water reflects light" when you are standing beside a pond. But, when you say "water" in that context, you actually are talking about the _surface_ of a _body_ of water. To be even more precise, you are talking about the _interface_ between two different transparent bodies; air and water. The air is as much a part of the phenomenon as the water. Only we don't say "air" because we are less aware of the air around us than, of the beautiful scenery, and the  picturesque pond before us.

Comment: @SolomonSlow If you want to be very specific it’s the electrons on those surface molecules.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The question is asking "*which of the following objects will you not see a reflection*?".

A distinction (albeit poorly) is being made between specular reflection and diffuse reflection.

The objects in options 1-3 will exhibit specular reflection, while option 4 "a book" will exhibit diffuse reflection. So the correct option will be "4 Book" since this object will not exhibit specular reflection, whereas "1. Polished metal, 2. Mirror" and "3. Undisturbed water" all exhibit specular reflection.

You are correct and the question should probably have been worded similar to this:

"*Which of the following objects would exhibit diffuse reflection, as oppose to specular reflection?*"

Now with the understanding that the question posed by the teacher was probably at  an elementary school level, it should be noted that a more technical answer (and more accurate answer) should explain these two forms of reflection in detail, so see more in the links below. But to briefly summarize:

[Diffuse reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection):

*Diffuse reflection is the reflection of light or other waves or particles from a surface such that a ray incident on the surface is scattered at many angles rather than at just one angle as in the case of specular reflection*.

[Specular reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection) is described as:

*Specular reflection, or regular reflection, is the mirror-like reflection of waves, such as light, from a surface.*

Comment: I don't think the correct answer to your last question would be "Book". Undisturbed water will reflect significantly less light than the pages of a book.

Comment: Even then,  "see[ing] your reflection" depends more on surface smoothness than on reflectivity

Comment: @noah Depends on the angle.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I was refering to the last question in the post, which says nothing about "your reflection".

Comment: @LawnmowerMan Yeah, but then the general answer "Book" is still wrong, if there are circumstances (most, even), where it is not true that water reflects more light than a book.

Comment: At an angle of zero to the normal, water reflects very little light, so this wording would still cause confusion.

Comment: @CramerTV Whether the photon that comes out of the object is the "same" photon is not a coherent question.

Comment: @Acccumulation, a *very* clever pun. Well done.

Comment: @Philip I disagree, although I freely admit it’s a question of semantics. When I say “reflection”, I’m talking about specular reflection (of which a book does very little). When I’m talking about the light seen from a book, I’d call it “scattered” light. I suspect the teacher uses similar nomenclature to conceptually distinguish scattered from specularly reflected light, and that’s the context within which this question makes sense.

Comment: **This answer is wrong,** and I’m shocked that it’s been upvoted so many times. “which objects reflect back most of the incident light, as oppose to objects that absorb most of the incident light” / “objects which reflect significantly more light than they absorb” These are orthogonal to whether you can see your own reflection in it (i.e. *specular* reflection). An object could (diffusely) reflect back a lot of light without showing your reflection, and conversely it could reflect back less light overall but show your reflection (a dark mirror).

Comment: @noah Agreed. Obsidian mirrors could be another example. Total reflectance ≠ specular reflectance, but this answer seems to conflate the two.

Comment: @Drjh I'd completely delete the statements referring to reflection/absorption *simpliciter*, since they repeat the teacher's mistake. I'd also explicitly state (in bold, at the beginning) that the teacher has confused overall reflection with *specular* reflection.

Answer (score 29):

In my opinion, one more thing which is possible here is that may be the question is

**Which among the following causes [**diffuse reflection**](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refln/Lesson-1/Specular-vs-Diffuse-Reflection)** ?

Undisturbed water can also give specular reflections but the surface of a book have many microscopic as well as macroscopic irregularities which causes **diffusion** of the reflected rays and thus you can't see your face on your book's surface like you do in mirrors.

Hope it helps .

Comment: Did you mean to use a block quote rather than a spoiler tag?

Comment: Indeed, if "book" is the intended answer, then the proper question is what you have stated.

Answer (score 19):

There are two main types of reflection:

1. specular (polished metal, mirror, undisturbed water)

[image]

In the case of specular reflection, the surface is on a micro level so smooth, that it is able to reflect (elastically scatter) all photons at the same as the incident angle.

On the image you can see your example of undisturbed water.

> Specular reflection reflects all light which arrives from a given direction at the same angle, whereas diffuse reflection reflects light in a broad range of directions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection

2. Diffuse (book)

[image]

> Diffuse reflection is the reflection of light or other waves or particles from a surface such that a ray incident on the surface is scattered at many angles rather than at just one angle as in the case of specular reflection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection

In the case of diffuse reflection, in your example the book, the surface might be non-absorbing (plaster, marble)  or absorbing (like a normal book cover).

In your case, the book has a surface that on the micro level is diffusely reflecting most of the incident photons, but it does absorb (and re-emit) a considerable portion of the incident photons too.

[image]

So the reason the book is the answer is that that is the only one that besides reflecting (diffusely) most photons, it does absorb and re-emit a considerable portion of photons too.

Please note that I was assuming that you only asked about visible wavelength photons.

Comment: Pictures sometimes explain more then words :-)

Comment: This should be the top answer. The current top answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 16):

Yeah, clearly this teacher regards the following two as synonymous: 'mirror reflection' and 'reflection'.

Presumably this teacher is unaware of the possibility/existence of diffuse reflection.

This means that in order to answer quiz questions by this teacher you need to try and reconstruct the thought process of the teacher, who may be dropping the ball left and right.

More generally: the choice of options illustrates how this teacher was struggling. The first three are general concepts:

1. polished metal
2. mirror
3. undisturbed water

The fourth one is oddly specific:

4. book

This teacher had the following problem: is there something that is guaranteed to have a dull surface?

This teacher took the easy way out, and took 'book'; a book is almost never glossy.

It would be interesting to try and think of something that is as general as the first three options, but has properties such that mirror reflection is inherently impossible.

(Of course, 'matte finished metal' is intentionally matte, hence guaranteed not to have mirror reflection, but then the property that the student is supposed to figure out is stated explicitly, defeating the purpose of the question.)

Comment: sand would be a "general" example of something that won't do specular reflection, along the same lines as undisturbed water.  Or plants.  (Polished / varnished wood is arguably not still a plant.)

Comment: @PeterCordes is a very shiny piece of fruit still a plant? 

Comment: @Tim: Are there any fruits that a truly *naturally* shiny, even after being washed by rain?  Our experience with shiny fruit usually involves them having been waxed after picking.  https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2017/04/why-fruit-has-a-fake-wax-coating/524619/ says *That grocery-store gloss is artificial fruit wax* (the whole article is about the history of that practice.)  But yeah, I was more sure about sand than plants; easy to imagine that there might be a few somewhat shiny plants I wasn't thinking of at the time.

Comment: @PeterCordes Pollia Condesta berries are quite reflective, but like most organic reflectivity it’s iridescent like a scarab beetle, rather than mirror like

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm leaning towards the manmade material felt. It's not quite a solid, but it's solid enough. (That is, unlike a pile of grains of sand it's a single object.) The surface is inherently coarse. Not that it can repair that question; that question is unsalvagable. Still, we will agree the underlying idea is good: to get the student to think about how the properties of a surface affect how light interacts with it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case where there's a word that technically refers to a general category, but is often used to refer to a particular subset of that category. The term "reflection" can refer to any redirection of light, but is often understood to refer to [specular reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection). If the teacher had asked "Which of the following objects do not specularly reflect light?" it would have been more precise, but then there would be students wondering what "specularly" means.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that if we can see anything in world, it is because that object reflects the light incident on it.

And I can see all objects in the list.

So, I think the answer is none of them.

Comment: So, You're saying, if somebody set a perfectly black object on a table in front of you, you would not be able to see it? (I agree, that you wouldn't be able to see the texture of its surface, but not see it at all???)

Comment: One rather needs to define "see" better before being able to answer that. Give me a definition of "see" and I well tell you whether it applies to a black body.

Our sense of shape and space is created in part by the way that re-reflections between objects create interactions between them. A truly black body might somehow create a weird absence-ness in the way that we perceive bulk and shape though shadow, specular highights and difuse colour-bleeds.

I can't prove it but suspect we would "see" a truly black object in a rather unsettling way.

Comment: You can see things that emit light too, even if they perfectly absorb all light that hits them.

Answer (score 0):

All surfaces reflect light except for light sources.
However, not all surfaces have specular reflection like a mirror as they reflect light well.
Now, let’s take a closer look at your question.

> 1.polished metal

> 2.mirror

> 3.undisturbed water

> 4.book

All of the give reflect light. However, options 1, 2 and 3 have specular reflection leaving 4 as the only one that has diffuse reflection. This question should have been phrased wrongly. The teacher might have thought of “Which of the following objects gives off diffuse reflection”.